# loading scripts and making sure they are present

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onload

I have an onload function that is loading d3...

```
var d3script = document.createElement("script");
d3script.src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js";
head.insertBefore(d3script, head.firstChild);

d3script.onload = function() { 
};
```

while another group of async's are running google Maps API calls.  I want to make it so that when the other async's finish and finally return their array, I can start doing d3 stuff.  What I don't know how to do is make it so that if:
A. d3 finishes loading first, it checks that the other array has returned before running
B. the array of async's returns first, it checks for d3 and if it's not there waits for it to load before doing d3 operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d3script = document.createElement("script");
d3script.src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js";

otherStuff.onload = function() {
     head.insertBefore(d3script, head.firstChild);

     d3script.onload = function() { 
         // do your stuff
     };
};
```